# UNPACK() 4 bytes into integer PHP sockets

Tags: php, sockets

I'm reading a socket, after all the issues thinking we were sending wrong information, it turns out something is wrong with reading.

The idea is:

```
1a- Get 4 bytes, unpack (95).
2a- Get 95 next bytes.
1b- Get 4 bytes, unpack (80).
2b- Get 80 next bytes.
```

I'm either unpacking wrong, or something is happening. The output I get is:

```
1a- get 4 bytes, unpacked=0.
2a- get 0 next bytes. (no return)
1b- get 4 bytes, unpacked=95.
2b- get 95 bytes, get $message.
```

$message is missing first 2 bytes, so I think it adds 2 at the end, taking from the 4 bytes which should be the next repetition. I think the problem stands at 0 bytes, or the unpacking is wrong.

```
while (!feof($connect)) {
        $i='';
        $size_get=fgets($fconnect, 4);
        $size=unpack('C',$size_get);
        echo fgets($connect, $size[1]) . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't passing unpack "C" telling it you want to unpack a single char? I think you want to pass it "L", for unsigned long.

Comment: Passing C is probably not the correct form, but L returns bool(false) if I var_dump($size)

Comment: If you print out `bin2hex($size_get);`, does it seem to contain the correct data? Also, note that `unpack` returns an array, not a single value.

Comment: Try either `var_dump(unpack("Nval", $size_get)['val']);` or `var_dump(unpack("Vval", $size_get)['val']);`.

Comment: those return errors. it won't even execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you read 4 bytes (`$size_get=fgets($fconnect, 4);`), but then you tell `unpack` that you're trying to unpack a single character with the `'C'` format. The different formats can be found in the documentation for [pack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php).

Taking this into account, here's a complete example that converts a string of bytes to a 32-bit unsigned integer:

```
<?php
$value = "\x12\x34\xAB\xCD";
echo "Value is: " . unpack("Nval", $value)['val'] . "\n";
?>
```

You can verify that this executes correctly and outputs the value one would expect ([305441741](https://www.google.com/#q=0x1234ABCD++in+decimal)) in this fiddle: http://ideone.com/PzbvXk.

For your particular problem, you'll change your code to:

```
$size = unpack("Nval", $size_get)['val'];
echo fgets($connect, $size) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: It does not execute. I'm not sure why. Do I need any specific packages for this?

Comment: Using the first part to verify, would not return anything. using $nr=unpack("Nval", $value); echo $nr['val']; returned the correct result. The problem is that I still can't get the desired result

Comment: Try adding `echo bin2hex($size_get);` to your function. Is the data you read what you expected? If yes, can you provide that data, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: CmdrMoozy is correct. After many attemts, turns out fgets() has a delimiter of sorts, and getting 4 bytes would not yield the correct pattern, which would not translate into the integer we needed. Using another socket method, worked.